# Smooth Transition On Hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've been working on finding a way to change out this `<img id="repair" src="http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/Repair.svg"` by using a `:hover`  with an image called `repair_h.svg`. What I initially was doing was placing a `:hover` on `#repair` like so `#repair :hover` and giving repair a  `background-image:url` but this was not working and I think there are a few reasons why.

That was my initial process...Since that did not work I did some research on how to achieve this correctly and found a way to achieve it with JS. Which is way less hackie than some other css and html solutions I was looking into.

Using JS ended up working great for the purpose of what I need done although there's one piece that I'd like to add to this and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I'd like to add a smooth transition between the image's when hovered on.

LINK TO MY CURRENT BUILD http://kapena.github.io/pp_web/
The icon I am working on here is called Repair Services

HTML

```
  <li> 
   <a href="#">
    <img id="repair" src="http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/Repair.svg"
     onmouseover="this.src='http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/hov/Repair_h.svg'" 
     onmouseout="this.src='http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/Repair.svg'" border="0" alt="About Plumbing Repairs in Honolulu Hawaii">
    </img>
   </a>
 </li>
```

JS

```
function hover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/hov/Repair_h.svg');
}

function unhover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/Repair.svg');
```

Also if any of you have any suggestions on away to perform a this entire task without JS and entirely with HTML and CSS then I'd be open to seeing how you'd do it :)

Thanks

Comment: CSS alternatives listed below- not sure if applicable to your scenario however

Comment: Do you know of a JS solution?

Comment: Also I am a bit confused as to what the span is doing? What is it's role here?

Comment: Do you have those images without the background?If yes then try applying background using css and then apply background-color-change and transition on hover.

Comment: An image is a replaced element, a type of element you cannot access pseudo (before, efter) elements for in CSS. As such, it is replaced with a span so we can get the before and after elements needed for the image transition

Comment: Perfect makes sense now! Thax @SW4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with markup and css only:

#### HTML:

```
 <a href="#">
    <img id="repair" src="http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/Repair.svg" border="0" 
        alt="About Plumbing Repairs in Honolulu Hawaii" />
 </a>
```

#### CSS:

```
a {
    background:url('http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/hov/Repair_h.svg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    width:150px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
}
a img {
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity .5s;
    float:left;
}
a:hover img {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity .5s;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kzwy9of7/)

Comment: This is really clean..I like it..I see what I was missing from the begging thax alot :)

Comment: Actually having issues with this bc I cant call just an `a` running into all my links when doing that..tried putting a class name on the `a` but that dose not seem to work with you're example.

Comment: You can try referencing to this anchor from its parent. like: `li#repairImg a{} li#repairImg a img{} `etc. that means you can give an id to the parent li.

Comment: I was having issues bc I left out `margin:0;
        padding:0;
        float:left;` thinking I did not need it..Turns out it did. Can you explain please why I need these properties?

Comment: To sum it up I basically just created a class here `<a class="repair-hov"` and then in the css I did just called `repair-hov` instead of calling the `img` I just called the id of `#repair`

Comment: @BrentWhite i applied these properties only for the demo only but `opacity and transition` is the property which needs to be used.

Comment: Got it to work perfectly and I skimmed this article http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/ which tells me about why you applied the `float` thax @Jai

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you cannot transition/animate directly between two images becuase CSS is incapable of interpolating keyframes between two none value-scale values.

That said, there are a few approaches using only CSS.

If you need to keep the same element/id the images are being transitioned on, the only approach would be to replace the image with a non-replaced element so you can use pseudo elements, then do e.g.:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

span:before,
span:after {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

span:before {
  content: url(http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/Repair.svg);
}

span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
  content: url(http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/hov/Repair_h.svg);
}

span:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Alternatively if this isnt a consideration, a common approach is to overlap two images and transition the `opacity` of the correct image on hover, revealing the image underneath.

```css
div:hover img:last-of-type {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
}
div:hover img:last-of-type {
  opacity: 0;
}
div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/Repair.svg" />
  <img src="http://d3vi9nkvdbmq5l.cloudfront.net/service-icons/hov/Repair_h.svg" />
</div>
```

Comment: The first version will most certainly do the trick for him :) Good answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the blue background from the image(s) and keep it transparent, you can do this easily with css:

```css
<style type="text/css">
  ul {
    list-style: none; 
  }

  a { 
        display: inline-block;
        width: 230px;
        height: 240px;
        background-color: #8bdafc;
        /* background-image: url(/path/to/img/with-transparent-bg.svg) */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
        -moz-transition: background-color .3s;
        -o-transition: background-color .3s;
        transition: background-color .3s;
    }

    a:hover {
        background-color: #4fc3fb;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Your repair text"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set an `src` attribute on the img

```
<img src='' width=500 height=500>

img{
  background: url("src1");
}

img:hover{
  background: url("src2");
}
```

Comment: I need to have alt text.

Comment: if your asking not necessarily but if you want yes go ahead that't fine

Comment: Well I need to have alt text in these images that's what I am saying. Do you think the JS method is not really needed?

Comment: wait are you generating images?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to leave out the src?

Comment: it is try it, put the attribute, but leave it empty

Comment: The images are being called through an http request

Comment: they always are but what exactly are you trying to do. because I assumed it was one img how are you generating or loading the images? because if your generating them, you need javascript